# Is it possible to cast a interface based mock into object?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, moq

in fact I have a mock object based on the interface. I would like to cast him into the real object..

```
    var BM = new Mock<DAL.INTERFACES.IMYCLASS>();
```

Is it possible to cast the mock to retrieve a MYCLASS object?

Thanks for responses..

Comment: BM.Object should contain the IMYCLASS implementation created by Moq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using moq allows you to test your class, which relies on other classes/interfaces, without needing to instantiate them.

If you want an instance of an object which implements your interface, you can simply call `Object` on your member:

```
var BM = new Mock<DAL.INTERFACES.IMYCLASS>();
BM.Object;
```

Don't forget to setup the required methods your testclass relies on. Further information can be found on the [QuickStart guide](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) on the [moq homepage](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

Comment: `Object` is actually a property, so it's `BM.Object;`, not `BM.Object();`

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not how most mocking libraries work.

What they do is create a whole new object, implementing the interface you ask for.

As such, the underlying object is not a MYCLASS object at all, it's something else altogether.

If you need to mock a concrete class, use a mocking library that can mock classes, and change your code to be (similar to):

```
var BM = new Mock<DAL.INTERFACES.MYCLASS>();
```

Comment: Yes but methods have to be virtual and this is not the case so I think I have to change Classes 
I test for => private MYCLASS _foo; to Private IMYCLASS _foo;

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the mocking libraries subclass the target type behind the scenes.

So when you ask for `Mock<IInterface>()`, you get an implementation of that interface, creates at rubtime like so:

```
//Your code

public interface IInterface {
 //methods
}

public class Implementation : IInterface{
  //methods
}

//At run time

public class IInterfaceImplementataionWithAReallyLongName354234234235423kjh23r54234 : IInterface {
 //methods
}
```

What you originally wanted to achieve is not actually possible because your implementation of `IInterface` is nowhere to be seen when Moq creates a proxy for you.